# PHP error unknown

Tags: php

So I have created a function:

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$unser_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1){
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id"));


        return $data;
    }

}
```

By mistake I crated a typo unser_id but didnt relise up until I had to troubleshoot further along the line in my code.

I am creating a login script but the point in which I am having to troubleshoot is showing profile data from my other users.

The reason I point out the typo part is because it for some reason is a strange error. If I change it to user_id it will not allow me to login anymore. If I leave it as under_id it works.

I am having to troubleshoot because I believe this is the cause of the problem I am having trying to view other users profiles and showing their information and not mine which is happening right now.

For example, in my url www.mywebsite.com/myprofile shows my username and my email address, if I type in www.mywebsite.com/otherprofile it still shows my information. But it does show a query if I type a user that does not exist in my database so that part works.

I believe the issue all stems form this typo but am really stuck as to appraoch a resolve?

So here is the other code:

profile page:

```
if (isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty ($_GET['username']) === false) {
    $username = $_GET['username'];



    if (user_exists($username) === true) {
        $user_id  = user_id_from_username($username);   
        $profile_data = user_data($user_id, 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

    ?>


    <p><?php echo $profile_data['profile']; ?></p>

    <h1><?php echo $profile_data['first_name']; ?> profile</h1>
    <p><?php echo $profile_data['email'] ?></p>



    <?php

    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, that user does not exist';
    }
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Here all the related functions:

```
function logged_in(){
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;    
}


function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}




function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}




function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id'); 
}




function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password' "), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

Comment: Make the habit of checking your query for errors. `if (!result) show_error`

Comment: I have to read this again, because the question is quite complex,but $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id"));  is a bit strange to me? `SELECT '$fields' from users where user_id = '$user_id'` I'd write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your first function is that you are quoting your column name with single quotes:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id"));
                                                                         ^       ^
```

That means that you are not actually using the column `user_id` but a string.

You should change that to:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));
```

(or without the backticks...).

Apart from that you are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and you don't have any error handling. You should switch to PDO or mysqli using prepared statements and make sure it throws exceptions (both can) so that you know exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: A: Thank you for spotting my error and B: by switching my mysql_query to mysqli_query?

Comment: The only thing I would suggest will be to check the query for error after running it. There is lots of potential for errors since the fields list is a variable and the nesting makes the error silent.

Comment: I found a great thread on converting the old mysql_query to PDO thanks for the advice

Comment: @user3746168 I prefer PDO myself as well, and as you probably already have realised, it is about changing all your database interaction, not just one function (and passing around / making available the connection, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the argument `$user_id` passed to `user_data` by `$unser_id`:

```
    $user_id = (int)$unser_id;
```

This way, the value of `$user_id` will always be whatever is stored in `$unser_id`, not what is passed to the function. You should try removing the line, so the code actually uses the user id you are passing it.

If you do not have any variable called `$unser_id` you should check the PHP error logs. I suspect there will be lines saying something like `Undefined variable: unser_id`.